# Prevent the use of a specific function in an output

Tags: special-functions, asymptotics

I am trying to asymptotically integrate a function with the code

`AsymptoticIntegrate[Exp[I k x + I/5 k^5], {k, 0, Infinity},  x -> Infinity]`

and the output is given in terms of the Meijer G function. This is not helpful for me, and I was wondering if there was a way I could explicitly tell Mathematica not to use this function in its output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version
```

> "12.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)"

```
AsymptoticIntegrate[
  Exp[I k x + I/5 k^5] // ComplexExpand, {k, 0, Infinity}, 
  x -> Infinity] // FullSimplify
```

> I/x

---

```
AsymptoticIntegrate[
   Exp[I k x + I/5 k^5] // ComplexExpand, {k, 0, Infinity}, 
   x -> Infinity] // RootReduce // N
```

$$\frac{0.\, +1. i}{x}+\frac{(\text{5.551115123125783$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-17}-\text{3.469446951953614$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-17} i) 2.71828^{0.8 x^{5/4}}}{x^{3/8}}$$

Using `//Chop` would give the previous result.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

int[x_] = 
 AsymptoticIntegrate[Exp[I k x + I/5 k^5], {k, 0, Infinity}, x -> Infinity]

(* -((Sqrt[5]
    MeijerG[{{1/2}, {}}, {{1/10, 1/5, 3/10, 2/5, 1/2, 3/5, 7/10, 4/5, 9/
      10}, {}}, -((I x)/10^(4/5)), 1/10])/(16 π^4 x)) + (
 I Sqrt[5] MeijerG[{{1}, {}}, {{1/10, 1/5, 3/10, 2/5, 3/5, 7/10, 4/5, 9/10, 
     1}, {}}, -((I x)/10^(4/5)), 1/10])/(16 π^4 x) *)
```

In this case, the [`MeijerG`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeijerG.html) can be expressed in terms of generalized hypergeometric functions ([`HypergeometricPFQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricPFQ.html)) which may or may not be acceptable for you.

```
(intFE[x_] = int[x] // FunctionExpand // ExpandAll // Simplify[#, x > 0] &)

(* (1/(4 Sqrt[2]))
 5^(1/5) (Sqrt[25 - 5 Sqrt[5]] + Sqrt[5 - Sqrt[5]] + 
    I Sqrt[2] (-1 + Sqrt[5])) Gamma[6/
   5] HypergeometricPFQ[{}, {1/5, 3/10, 2/5, 1/2, 7/10, 4/5, 9/10}, x^10/
   100000000] + (1/(8 Sqrt[2]))
 5^(2/5) (Sqrt[5 + Sqrt[5]] + 
    I (Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[10] + I Sqrt[5 (5 + Sqrt[5])])) x Gamma[7/
   5] HypergeometricPFQ[{}, {3/10, 2/5, 1/2, 3/5, 4/5, 9/10, 11/10}, x^10/
   100000000] - (1/(
 50 Sqrt[2] 5^(2/5)
   Gamma[7/5]))(5 Sqrt[2] (-1 + Sqrt[5]) + 
    2 I Sqrt[5 (5 + Sqrt[5])]) π x^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{}, {2/5, 1/2, 3/5,
     7/10, 9/10, 11/10, 6/5}, x^10/
   100000000] + (11 (-2 I Sqrt[5 - Sqrt[5]] + 
      Sqrt[2] (5 + Sqrt[5])) π x^3 HypergeometricPFQ[{}, {1/2, 3/5, 7/10, 
      4/5, 11/10, 6/5, 13/10}, x^10/100000000])/(250 Sqrt[2] 5^(7/10)
     Gamma[16/
     5]) + (x^4 (-(1/Gamma[19/5])
       51038926848 (2 I Sqrt[25 - 5 Sqrt[5]] + 
          5 (Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[10])) π x HypergeometricPFQ[{}, {7/10, 4/5, 9/
          10, 6/5, 13/10, 7/5, 3/2}, x^10/100000000] + (1/Gamma[18/5])
      10531842048 5^(
       1/5) (5 Sqrt[2] (-1 + Sqrt[5]) - 
         2 I Sqrt[5 (5 + Sqrt[5])]) π x^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{}, {4/5, 9/
         10, 11/10, 13/10, 7/5, 3/2, 8/5}, x^10/100000000] - 
      3125 5^(1/
        10) (3125 5^(
          3/10) (Sqrt[5 + Sqrt[5]] - 
            I (Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[10] - I Sqrt[5 (5 + Sqrt[5])])) x^3 Gamma[33/
           5] HypergeometricPFQ[{}, {9/10, 11/10, 6/5, 7/5, 3/2, 8/5, 17/10}, 
           x^10/100000000] + 
         1196 (25 (Sqrt[25 - 5 Sqrt[5]] + 5 Sqrt[5 - Sqrt[5]] + 
               I Sqrt[2] (-5 + Sqrt[5])) x^4 Gamma[19/
              5] HypergeometricPFQ[{}, {11/10, 6/5, 13/10, 3/2, 8/5, 17/10, 9/
               5}, x^10/100000000] - 
            56 I Sqrt[2] 5^(
             7/10) (3024 HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {3/5, 7/10, 4/5, 9/10, 11/10, 
                  6/5, 13/10, 7/5}, x^10/100000000] - 
               x^5 HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {11/10, 6/5, 13/10, 7/5, 8/5, 17/10,
                   9/5, 19/10}, x^10/100000000])))))/(15190156800000 Sqrt[2]
     5^(4/5)) *)
```

However, since you are only interested in the asymptotic behavior

```
intFEa[x_] = 
 Asymptotic[intFE[x], {x, Infinity, 3}] // FullSimplify[#, x > 0] &

(* I/x *)
```

Alternatively,

```
int2[x_] = Assuming[x > 0, Integrate[Exp[I k x + I/5 k^5], {k, 0, Infinity}]];

int2A[x_] = 
 Asymptotic[int2[x], x -> Infinity] // Developer`GammaSimplify // 
  FullSimplify[#, x > 0] &

(* I/x *)
```